# Square root of a symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices

If we consider a square matrix $A$ that is positive definite and symmetric, we know that there exists a unique square root $B$ such that $A=B^{t}B$, however is this matrix $B$ symmetric ?

Thank you !

Comment: $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&2\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: The answer is no. Note in general that if $B^tB = A$, then for any orthogonal matrix $U$ the matrix $C = UB$ satisfies $C^tC = A$.